# How to send id from fragment to activity?

Tags: android

Hello i am new to android,in my app i am getting more than one users list in `Listview` using `json` and it has one unique id it looks like this.

I am getting this data perfectly in my apps,now in this `json` i have matching_id which unique now i want to get user profile as per this id in second page and its `json` looks like this lets take `id=636` so i want to get details..

**Homefragment class**

```
    public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

    //CustomAdapter adapter;
    //private List<RowItem> rowItems;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONArray matching=null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> aList;
    private static String MATCH_URL = null;
    private static final String TAG_MATCH="matching";
    private static final String TAG_MATCH_ID="match_detail_id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME="name";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE="profile_id";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
    private static final String TAG_CAST="cast";
    private static final String TAG_AGE="age";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION="location";

    private ListView listview;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String strtext = getArguments().getString("user_login_id");
         MATCH_URL = "http://abcsd.com/webservice/matching?version=apps&user_login_id="+strtext;
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

       // rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        listview=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        new LoadAlbums().execute();



        return rootView;
    }

    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeFragment.this.getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(MATCH_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    matching = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_MATCH);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < matching.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = matching.getJSONObject(i);




                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String user_match_id=c.getString(TAG_MATCH_ID);
                        String user_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String user_profile=c.getString(TAG_PROFILE);
                        String user_image=c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                        String user_cast=c.getString(TAG_CAST);
                        String user_age=c.getString(TAG_AGE);
                        String user_location=c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);



                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MATCH_ID, user_match_id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME,user_name);
                        map.put(TAG_PROFILE, user_profile);
                        map.put(TAG_IMAGE, user_image);
                        map.put(TAG_CAST, user_cast);
                        map.put(TAG_AGE, user_age+" years");
                        map.put(TAG_LOCATION, user_location);



                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        aList.add(map);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            super.onPostExecute(file_url);
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread

                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),aList);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

                }

        }




}
```

this is working fine now in next activity i want to get full details as per second `json`.

in below activity i want to get users detail what should i do?

```
public class ProfilePage extends Activity{

private ImageView cover;
private ImageView yes;
private ImageView no;
private ImageView sendmsg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_page);

    cover=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.coverimage);
    yes=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yesbutton);
    no=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nobutton);
    sendmsg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgsendmsgg);
    sendmsg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfilePage.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.title_alertbox_upgrade)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                   .setMessage(R.string.chek_upgrade)
                   .setCancelable(true)
                   .setNegativeButton(R.string.okalert_upgrade, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });

            AlertDialog welcomeAlert = builder.create();
            welcomeAlert.show();
            // Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()
            ((TextView)welcomeAlert.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            /*// Creating alert Dialog with one Button

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ProfileEdit.this).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Edit Profile");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Please log on to gujjumatch.com desktop site to edit your profile " +
                    "and also set other details or call on 91 281 3054120");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            // Setting OK Button
            alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            // closed
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();*/


        }
    });
    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 

    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                      (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yes);

            // set a message
            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Interest Sent");



            // Toast...
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();

        }
    });

    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                      (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);

            // set a message
            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text.setText("Interest Declined");



            // Toast...
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();

        }
    });
    cover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Fullimage.class);
               // passing array index


               startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

 }
```

Comment: Make interface for and make a method in it and call that method in your fragment after implements your fragment with interface and its callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your `ListView` within fragment class.

I assume that you can create ListView with ease ...

Now on click of ListView you need to pass data like this ..

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UserBrandsFragmentDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("brand_logo", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).brand_logo); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You require to have ListView. Then on click of ListView you need to use my above mentioned code ...

In my above mentioned code "lv" is ListView. :)

On your next activity you need to get that data using bundle ...like this.

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String your_data = extra.getString("your_key_while_parsing_data_through_Intent");
```

That's it .. you are good to go!!

For creating list view you can Google it. There's lot of tutorial available for that.

Let me know if you still have any sort of query ..

Answer (score 0):

Start a new activity/Fragment in onitemclick of listview and Pass the "match_detail_id" in extra.

If you use activity use putExtra and getExtra.
If you use fragment use

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and

```
fragment.getArguments() //in oncreate of fragment.
```

and get the full details in oncreate of the Activity/Fragment